# Netbeans with Oracle connection java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, netbeans6.5

I use NetBeans 6.5.

When I try to run the following code:

```
package com.afrikbrain.numeroteur16;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author 
*/

public class NumeroteurTest {

  public NumeroteurTest() {

  }

  public void doIt() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    try {

      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","user","pwd");
      String newNUMERO = new Numeroteur16("MATCLI", connection).numeroter();
      System.out.println("NUMERO GENERE : "+newNUMERO.toString());
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NumeroteurTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NumException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            new NumeroteurTest().doIt();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NumeroteurTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Driver not found.");
        }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at com.afrikbrain.numeroteur16.NumeroteurTest.doIt(NumeroteurTest.java:27)
        at com.afrikbrain.numeroteur16.NumeroteurTest.main(NumeroteurTest.java:45)
Driver not found.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: Java can't find the JDBC Driver Class.
Solution: Add the Oracle JDBC Driver to your classpath.
You can get it at http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html

Start java with `java -classpath ojdbc14.jar ...` to include the downloaded jar in your classpath.

Comment: here is it http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/11202/ojdbc6.jar

Answer (score 1):

Add `ojdbc6.jar` to the project libraries. First, create a new library (NetBeans):

- *NetBeans -> Tools -> Libraries -> New library* (Use a descriptive name eg: OracleJDBC6.)
- Click *OK*, then *Add JAR/Folder*.
- Type `%ORACLE_HOME%\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar`, then confirm. On my computer, `ORACLE_HOME=c:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1`.

Finally, add the library to the project: Right-click on *Libraries*, , select *Add library* and select the library previously added.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Oracle driver is in the classpath. The thin driver is in ojdbc14.jar.